# MD5 wasn't changed?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, md5

I have 3 rar files (all with the same md5), and I use this code to change Md5:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set /A Counter=0


FOR %%1 in (*.rar) do (

        set /A Counter= !Counter! + 1
                COPY  %%1+!Counter!
                echo !Counter!

)

pause
```

When I run the .bat file, it shows 3 row with value: 1, 2, 3 but when I check md5 of 3 rar files, they is same although they were changed. Why ? What wrong I did? Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you are changing anything, as you forgot to add a destination file in the copy command, as written [here](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html).

Comment: @DoktoroReichard That's not the actual issue: "When you combine files, [and] you omit *Destination*, the files are combined and stored under the name of the first file in the list." [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771997.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the files '.\1', '.\2' and '.\3' do not exist. The copy command `copy archive.rar+1` appends the content of file '1' to the .rar file. If the file does not exist, it is treated as if it were empty. The hash changes nonetheless because without the '/b' flag, the command also appends the character 0x1A. Since all files found with (*.rar) were the same to begin with, adding the same bytes to every one will result in three exact same .rar files with the exact same MD5.

You can make sure the MD5 values are different after running the script by creating the files '.\1', '.\2' etc. with different contents. If you simply want to append the characters, you may want to use something like `echo !Counter! >> %%1` instead. The resulting files will not be valid rar archives anymore, of course. For that, you will need a rar tool with a command line interface.

Comment: Actually, the user doesn’t say that the three files are identical, only that they have the same MD5 hash. Of course, if he has a way of generating non-identical files with the same MD5 hash, he could probably get that published.

Answer (score 1):

Your batch script has some issues. What you're trying to do is to append a number to the end of the original files in order to change their MD5 hashes. However:

- The plus sign (`+`) can only be used to combine multiple existing files.
- You're dealing with binary files, so you need to use the `/b` parameter.

  > `/b` directs the command interpreter to read the number of bytes specified by the file size in the directory. `/b` is the default value for `copy`, unless `copy` combines files.
  >
  > When `/b` precedes or follows a list of files on the command line, it applies to all listed files until copy encounters `/a`.
  >
  > <sub>Source: [Copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771997.aspx)</sub>

Basically you need to store the number you want to append in a temporary file, and then combine it with the original `.rar` archive. Here's a fixed, working version:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set tempFile=%temp%\%random%%random%.tmp
set /a counter=0

for %%G in (*.rar) do (
set /a counter += 1
<nul set /p=!counter!>"%tempFile%"
copy /b "%%~G"+"%tempFile%" >nul
echo !counter!
)

del "%tempFile%" 2>nul    
pause

endlocal & exit /b
```

**Note** Replace `for` with `for /r` if you want to recursively scan folders.

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)